# MATLAB Discretizing Sine Function with +/-

Tags: matlab

Hello I am relatively new to MATLAB and have received and assignment in which we could use any programming language. I would like to continue MATLAB and have decided to use it for this assignment. The questions has to do with the following formula:

x(t) = A[1+a1*E(t)]*sin{w[1+a2*E(t)]*t+y}(+/-)a3*E(t)

The first question we have is to develop an appropriate discretization of x(t) with a time step h. I think i understand how to do this using step but because there is a +/- in the end I am running into errors. Here is what I have (I have simplified the equation by assigning arbitrary values to each variable):

```
A  = 1;
E  = 1;
a1 = 1;
a2 = 2;
a3 = 3;
w  = 1;
y  = 0;
% ts = .1;
% t  = 0:ts:10;
t  = 1:1:10;


x1(t) = A*(1+a1*E)*sin(w*(1+a2*E)*t+y);
x2(t) = a3*E;
y(t) = [x1(t)+x2(t), x1(t)-x2(t)]
plot(y)
```

The problem is I keep getting the following error because of the +/-:

In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.

Error in Try1 (line 21)
y(t) = [x1(t)+x2(t), x1(t)-x2(t)]

Any help?? Thanks!

Comment: the error is because: `y(t)` can hold only one element corresponding one value of t. You are trying to assign a row vector of two elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `(t)` from the left-hand side of all three assignments.

```
y = [x1+x2, x1-x2]
```

MATLAB knows what to do with vectors and matrices.

Or, if you want to write it out the long way, tell MATLAB there will be two columns:

```matlab
y(t, 1:2) = [x1(t)'+x2(t)', x1(t)'-x2(t)']
```

or two rows:

```matlab
y(1:2, t) = [x1(t)+x2(t); x1(t)-x2(t)]
```

But this won't work when you have fractional values of `t`.  The value in parentheses is required to be the index, not a dependent variable.  If you want the whole vector, just leave it out.

Comment: Thank you very much I will continue with the problem and come here for questions! Amazed at how fast that was answered!